# how to filter multiple serializer in django rest framework

Tags: filter, django-rest-framework

I jush has one models which has two fields, one is post, anther is a foreignkey which be related the django User model.like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
```

now I definde a User serializer contrains the Post,just like this:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'post', 'author')

class UserSerialzier(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    posts = PostSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'snippets', 'posts')
```

I just want to return a json which contain the user data and the post data. but, I want to get the post data which is filter by the condition,not all of the post data, my view is like this:

```
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    serializer_class = HomeSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        post_set = self.request.user.posts.filter(post='python')
        query_set = User.objects.filter(posts=post_set, username='admin')
        return query_set
```

I wish to get the result :

```
{
    "id": 1, 
    "username": "rsj217", 
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "post": "python", 
            "author": {
                "id": 1, 
                "username": "rsj217", 
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "post": "python", 
            "author": {
                "id": 1, 
                "username": "rsj217", 
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but in fact , I get the result like this :

```
{
    "id": 1, 
    "username": "rsj217", 
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "post": "python", 
            "author": {
                "id": 1, 
                "username": "rsj217", 
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "post": "python", 
            "author": {
                "id": 1, 
                "username": "rsj217", 
            }
        },
         {
            "id": 3, 
            "post": "ruby", 
            "author": {
                "id": 1, 
                "username": "rsj217", 
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can not filter the post field "ruby"??? , I do not know where has go away

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you retrieve your queryset is wrong. Try it like this:

```
    query_set = User.objects.filter(post__in=post_set, username='admin')
```

Comment: my models is `author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')`,the `related_name` is `posts`. when I change the post_set, it does not work.